# How to generate keyphrase, mnemonic, seed, private key and public key on the Solana Blockchain

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

How to generate a keyphrase, mnemonic, seed, private key and public key on the Solana Blockchain (Mainet, Testnet & Devnet)?

Answer (score -1):

**STEP 1**

```
// Install solana and bip39 module

npm install @solana/web3.js bip39
```

**STEP 2**

```
//import solana npm module
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
```

**STEP 3**

```
/*SOLANA
 *https://api.testnet.solana.com - Testnet rpc
 *https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com - mainet rpc
 *https://api.devnet.solana.com - devnet rpc
*/ 

//create a new instance of solana connection
  const Solana = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
    "https://api.testnet.solana.com"
  );
```

**STEP 4**

```
  const generateSolanaAddress = async () => {
    let mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
    const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic); 

    // const recentBlock = await Solana.getEpochInfo();
    // console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NEW BLOCK~~~~~~~~~~~~\n", recentBlock);
    //const keyPair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();
    let a = new Uint8Array(seed.toJSON().data.slice(0,32))
    var kp = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSeed(a);
  
    console.log("Public Key:", kp.publicKey.toString());

    console.log("Secret Key:",kp.secretKey);

    console.log("Seed Phrase:", mnemonic);

    console.log("Keypair:", kp);
  };
```

**STEP 5**
RESULT
[image]